# Get list of routes generated by framework in Zend 1.1

Tags: zend-framework

In Zend 1.1, the routes correspond to controller/action names. Is there a way to get a list of all the available routes via command line or script?

I can find it manually but is there a way to get it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is easy

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$routes = $front->getRouter()->getRoutes();

foreach ($routes as $routeName=>$route) {
    echo $routeName . ': ' . get_class($route) . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Prints a very horrific object hierarchy. Any idea how to get routes/params from this?

Comment: ZF1 routes params depends on route class, so every route should be parsed depending on its class

Comment: Perfect! Your edited answer is what solves my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just one more question, this seems to be displaying only the custom routes defined manually.  What about the routes that correspond to controller/action in zend?